# How to get repeated element from For-Each in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to get repeated elements in XSLT 2.0. But there is a restriction that i have to do that only with using "For-each" loop.

**Input XML:**

```
<Data>
<Movie>
<name>A</name>
<writer>B</writer>
<writer>C</writer>
<director>D</director>
</Movie>
<Movie>
<name>A</name>
<writer>B</writer>
<writer>C</writer>
<director>D</director>
</Movie>
</Data>
```

**Expected Output XML:**

```
<Imdb>
<Film>
<writer>B</writer>
<writer>C</writer>
</Film>
<Film>
<writer>B</writer>
<writer>C</writer>
</Film>
</Imdb>
```

**Current Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Imdb>
   <Film>
      <writer>B</writer>
      <writer>B</writer>
   </Film>
</Imdb>
```

**MyXSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Film>

 <xsl:for-each select="Movie">
  <writer>     
<xsl:value-of select="writer" />
</writer>
</xsl:for-each>
        </Film>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Note:**

I need to achieve the above mentioned task only with for each loop or for each group by loop. So anyone can please help.

Comment: If you're constrained to only use some language constructs and not others, it's always a good idea to explain why. None of us like working within artificial constraints unless we know they are there for a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:template match="/Data">
    <Imdb>
        <xsl:for-each select="Movie">
            <Film>
                <xsl:copy-of select="writer"/>
            </Film>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Imdb>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't know what you mean by:

> I need to achieve the above mentioned task only with for each loop or
>   for each group by loop.

Surely you want to achieve the above task using the most efficient code possible?

Comment: But can you please do it with for-each loop. Thanks. Its a requirement in my case.

Comment: @user3141034 You can replace `<xsl:copy-of select="writer"/>` with `<xsl:for-each select="writer">` and put `<xsl:value-of select="." />` inside.